# Without "TextView" in code, "LinearLayout.LinearParams" not increasing margin

Tags: android, android-layout

In this code i just wanted to change the margin when i click on button. but the problem is that this code is working until this line `((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Changed at runtime!");` is presented in code. if I remove this line the margin is not increasing when i am pressing the button.

This example is from a book "Android Application Development Cookbook", but there is no explanation for this and I didn't find any any thing much helpful about `LinearLayout.LinearParams` on android website. so any help is appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Changed at runtime!");
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
            params.leftMargin += 5;
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click"
    android:id="@+id/button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your activity_main xml also. It seems your textView is assign wrap_content property in xml. which results in no change if the textView is empty.

Comment: @nnn xml added. please take a look..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the LayoutParams again to the view like this,

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
    params.leftMargin += 5;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: whould you please tell me what is exactly the last line doing.

Comment: Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view.

Comment: thanks, it worked :) , but why in my previous code margin was not increasing without `TextView`.

Comment: it's in the question. but i didn't use `view.setLayoutParams(params);` in that. and that worked only if there is `TextView` view. if `TextView` is removed code is not working. and the book i am following did't tell me about `view.setLayoutParams(params);`. so thank you.

Comment: With the previous code , you have both views in the same parent linear layout  so any layout changes in the TextView will make the LinearLayout to take a requestLayout() so it will redraw all the child views.